React Native CLI Web app React Native Stack Navigation Drawer doesn't work (Drawer and Reanimated issue)
I have a problem with the Drawer in React Native CLI in my web application (drawer works correctly in Android App). I cant run my web app, because of this problem:
ERROR in ./node_modules/@react-navigation/drawer/lib/module/views/legacy/Drawer.js 64:26-40
export 'default'.'Value' (imported as 'Animated') was not found in 'react-native-reanimated' (possible exports: FlatList, Image, ScrollView, Text, View, addWhitelistedNativeProps, addWhitelistedUIProps, createAnimatedComponent)
ERROR in ./node_modules/@react-navigation/drawer/lib/module/views/legacy/Drawer.js 65:25-39
export 'default'.'Value' (imported as 'Animated') was not found in 'react-native-reanimated' (possible exports: FlatList, Image, ScrollView, Text, View, addWhitelistedNativeProps, addWhitelistedUIProps, createAnimatedComponent)
ERROR in ./node_modules/@react-navigation/drawer/lib/module/views/legacy/Drawer.js 382:42-55
export 'default'.'Code' (imported as 'Animated') was not found in 'react-native-reanimated' (possible exports: FlatList, Image, ScrollView, Text, View, addWhitelistedNativeProps, addWhitelistedUIProps, createAnimatedComponent)
ERROR in ./node_modules/@react-navigation/drawer/lib/module/views/legacy/Drawer.js 386:77-90
export 'default'.'Code' (imported as 'Animated') was not found in 'react-native-reanimated' (possible exports: FlatList, Image, ScrollView, Text, View, addWhitelistedNativeProps, addWhitelistedUIProps, createAnimatedComponent)

I've updated my babel.config.js file to:
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:@react-native/babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from',
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
  ],
};

I also copied import react-native-gesture-handler; in the top of my entry file (App.jsx).

Package versions:
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.18.9",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.15",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.17",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.26",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.29",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.16.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.8.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.9.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.30.1",
    "react-native-web": "^0.19.10",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },

This is react native project & same code working for android & Web. Drawer is working on android there is any issue but in web browser giving that error and i have many try to fixe it but not working. is there any body one know idea about it.
